# How to get a MySQL/html test server working with Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: linux, mysql, samba

I recently started my old samba server again and I am using the website (connected to the ip) in /var/www/html and I want to use it to test my new skills testing databses with MySQL and SQL.

Except I connect MySQL to my server but require a 'MySQL IP', which I do not have, or don't know how to setup.

I am quite new to this server-side stuff and have little experience in it. But I would like to test SQL servers, MySQL, PHP and HTML, CSS and JS.

So I how do I setup a MySQL server? Is it free? And what does it do?

I could not find anything on google so I resorted to asking this question.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking isn't really clear, since I don't understand what you want, but I'll try to explain.

Setting up a MySQL Server on Linux is pretty simple, you can follow [this tutorial](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-mysql-server-on-the-ubuntu-operating-system/). After that, you can remotely access the MySQL Server using :3306 (default MySQL port).

By the way, you cannot access a MySQL database with HTML (that's what I understood by reading the title). You'll need a programming language like PHP or JavaScript (you may use Node JS if you're working server-side).

**EDIT:** I've read again what you wrote. You're speaking about SQL Server and MySQL. Those products are not the same, since one is coming from Microsoft and the other one is from Oracle. You can check the min differences by clicking on [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-mysql-and-sql-server).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am able to use use PHP with my server (I set it up to use PHP and not show the code). Thank you. Except I am unable to connect to it on the MySQL workbench. Thanks though

Comment: You're welcome :) you cannot connect to MySQL Workbench through what? Your Web server? Or through PHP?

Comment: Well, I can not connect to my database (mysql-server). I am using 127.0.0.1:3306, but am unable to connect

Comment: Yes, but with PHP or MySQL Workbench?
And which error message do you have?